# I have problem while setting virtual environment for django

Tags: python, django

```
Python 3.11.3
PS C:\Users\DELL> pip --version
pip 23.1.2 from C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)
PS C:\Users\DELL> py -m venv myworld
Error: Command '['C:\\Users\\DELL\\myworld\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
PS C:\Users\DELL>  py -m venv myworld
Error: Command '['C:\\Users\\DELL\\myworld\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
PS C:\Users\DELL> myworld\Scripts\activate.bat
myworld\Scripts\activate.bat : The module 'myworld' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module
myworld'.
At line:1 char:1
+ myworld\Scripts\activate.bat
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (myworld\Scripts\activate.bat:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule
```

The error occurred as above.